How do I add a dedication page in cleanthesis latex template?
I am using the clean thesis latex template on overleaf, and I would like to add a dedication page.
I tried adding this command to the main.tex, but I got an error.
How might one add a dedication page in the cleanthesis latex template? Thank you!
\newcommand{\dedication}[1]{
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
  \begin{flushright}
    \emph{#1}
  \end{flushright}
  \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\dedication{To my family.}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
% Your document content goes here

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! please make your code snippet be compilable and tell us the error message you got! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Thank you. I'm afraid I don't know how to make it compilable... since it's quite a big latex template... but the error is that it says the dedication is already defined and when I compile the document, there's nothing that shows up

\dedication is a standard command for the book and article LaTeX classes, and also for the scrreprt class on which cleanthesis is based. So you get an error that it is already defined. For your case you should use a different command name, e.g. \newcommand{\dedic}.
